# KeyError: 'this' , why this error happened?

Tags: python, keyerror

```
CORPUS = [
        'this is the first document',
        'this is the second document',
        'and this is the third document',
        'is this the first document ?'
    ]

doc = CORPUS
dic = {}
for sentence in doc:
  k = list(sentence.split())
  for term in k:
    count_term = k.count(term)
    if not dic[term]:
      dic[term] = count_term
    else:
      dic[term] += count_term
print(dic)
```

I want to count a frequency for the terms in the sentences in CORPUS list, so I tried to make a dictionary and input the count object but KeyError: 'this'

Could you explain why the error happened?

Comment: `if not dic[term]` fails if there's no key. Test with `in`: `if not term in dic:...`

Comment: [KeyError](https://realpython.com/python-keyerror/) is one of the simpler problems to debug in Python. A small amount of debugging on your part will almost always resolve this quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, your code can be simplified to:

```
from collections import Counter

print(Counter(" ".join(CORPUS).split()))
```

which yields

```
Counter({'this': 4,
         'is': 4,
         'the': 4,
         'first': 2,
         'document': 4,
         'second': 1,
         'and': 1,
         'third': 1,
         '?': 1})
```

So, the idea is to first create one long string which avoids the loop and then use a built-in function to count the occurrences of the individual words.

The reason for the error you get is well explained in the other two answers (I upvoted both of them) :)

Answer (score 2):

you should change the condition:

`if not dic[term]` to `if term not in dic`

Comment: I really appreciate you!! You solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

If the key is not in the dictionary it will throw `KeyError`, it won't return `None`. You can check if the key is in the dictionary

```
for term in k:
    count_term = k.count(term)
    if term not in dic:
        dic[term] = count_term
    else:
        dic[term] += count_term
```

or use `get()` with default value, this will return 0 in case the key is not in the dictionary

```
for term in k:
    count_term = k.count(term)
    dic[term] = dic.get(term, 0) + count_term
```